# How to read MongoDB .mdmp files

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

My MongoDB 3.6.2 craches randomly.

It provides .mdmp files in the location where I installed MongoDB. The only problem is I don't know how to read these binary files.

mongod.2017-12-21T08-01-49.mdmp

Does anyone knows how to read these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to consider opening an issue on [MongoDB's Issue Tracker](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) and providing the `*.mdmp` file in the issue.

---

`*.mdmp` files are considered to be Microsoft Dump Files.

> Compressed file created by Windows after a program error or crash; contains data "dumped" from the program's memory space; saves information about the error, which can be used for debugging; commonly created along with an uncompressed .HDMP file and can be sent to Microsoft as part of a bug reporting process.

***Reference:*** [.MDMP File Extension](https://fileinfo.com/extension/mdmp) (fileinfo.com)

If you have a Microsoft debugger and the symbols for the relevant progams, then you can have a look at the dump file yourself:

> A dump file is a snapshot of an app at the point in time the dump is taken. It shows what process was executing and what modules were loaded. If the dump was saved with heap information, the dump file contains a snapshot of what was in the app's memory at that point in time. Opening a dump file with a heap in Visual Studio is like stopping at a breakpoint in a debug session. Although you cannot continue execution, you can examine the stacks, threads, and variable values of the app at the time the dump occurred.

But be aware:

> Debugging dump files of optimized code can be confusing. For example, compiler inlining of functions can result in unexpected call stacks and other optimizations might change the lifetime of variables.

Debugging a kernel-mode dump file requires you to...

> To debug kernel-mode dump files in Visual Studio 2013, download the [Windows 8.1 Version of Debugging Tools for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/gg463009). See [Kernel Debugging in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/jj149675.aspx).

***Reference:*** [Using Dump Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5zhxt22.aspx) (Microsoft MSDN)

---

There are some third-party tool from NirSoft that might help in finding the culprit.

And then there is the following list that tells you which tools could possibly open the `*.mdmp` file for you:

[.mdmp Extension - List of programs that can open .mdmp files](http://extension.nirsoft.net/mdmp) (Extension NirSoft)

> **Disclaimer:**
>   I am in no way affiliated with NirSoft. I only use their software.

Answer (score -1):

> What is an MDMP file?

I am sure you are doing mistake, as (`MDMP`) extension file is not supported to **`MongoDB`**. As per `MSDN BOL` [Here](https://fileinfo.com/extension/mdmp) MDMP file is Compressed file created by Windows after a program error or crash; contains data "dumped" from the program's memory space; saves information about the error, which can be used for debugging; commonly created along with an uncompressed `.HDMP` file and can be sent to Microsoft as part of a bug reporting process.

Compressed Heap Dump files are saved as Minidump (`.MDMP`) files and may be sent to Microsoft as part of an error reporting and bug fixing process.

Windows Error Reporting settings are stored in the Windows Registry at `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting."`

NOTE: You typically should not open `HDMP` files unless diagnosing a program crash in a controlled software environment.

**Note: -** `MongoDB` supports **`JavaScript Object Notation`** (`JSON`) and **`Binary JSON`** (**`BSON`**) format only.**`BSON`** extends the **`JSON`** model to provide additional data types, ordered fields, and to be efficient for encoding and decoding within different languages.

For further your ref [Here](https://www.mongodb.com/json-and-bson) and [Here](https://fileinfo.com/extension/hdmp)

Comment: Minidump files include some context on the state of a process (in this case `mongod.exe`) which is captured when the process aborts unexpectedly. These files aren't specifically for Microsoft to analyze (unless generated by one of Microsoft's applications); the minidumps are generally only meaningful for the developers of the application which created the minidump. Minidump files have no relation to MongoDB's storage format, JSON, or BSON - they are a standard Windows diagnostic/debugging aid for software developers.