# SQL server 2016 - .mdmp file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

How do I read a mdmp file. Server failed generating SQL dump files which are in .mdmp format. How do I read them.

Comment: Check [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8a98c7cb-cdc9-4290-a865-362004660f8c/how-to-read-mdmp-files-generated-by-sql-server-?forum=sqldatabaseengine). Basic recommendation is that, unless you're used to using Windows debugger tools, your best bet for help w/ those is MS Support.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by reading the memory dump of a 3rd party program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read MongoDB .mdmp files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198446/how-to-read-mongodb-mdmp-files)

Answer (score 4):

When SQL Server crashes and generates a minidump file (.mdmp) your best bet is to contact Microsoft Support and have them analyze it.

The [SQL Server Diagnostics](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/sql-server-diagnostics-preview/) has been discontinued unfortunately.

If you are bold enough you could open the minidump in [windbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools) but I wouldn't bet the farm on getting anything out of it yourself.
[This article](https://blobeater.blog/2017/06/14/windbg-and-sql-server-fun/) could get you started.

I'd just open a pss case.